# Does redux wait for previous actions changes to flow down as props before dispatching next action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to redux. I have this question, i can't find any good blogs or explanation regarding this. 
Thank-you.

Comment: by default Redux is synchronous in nature, so yes. One action/reduction task has to come and go before the next can happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the previous changes will flow down as props before dispatching next action, please refer to this diagram below:

[Redux Diagram without API Middleware](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/5aba89b6daab934631adffc1f301d17bb273268b/68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f6d656469612d702e736c69642e65732f75706c6f6164732f3336343831322f696d616765732f323438343535322f415243482d5265647578322d7265616c2e676966)

Comment: Thanks, this gif really helps.